# Why Magento 2.1.2 cannot delete watermark?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, watermark

After Going `Content->Design->Configuration->Product Image Watermarks`

Deleting and Saving the Configuration

Reloading the page and it is still there

Flippen annoying

Comment: Made some tests and it works fine on my side. Maybe it's a permission issue ?

Comment: Permissions on what folder?

Comment: I'd say `pub/media`